# Background color of link not changing when hovered over twitter bootstrap's dropdown menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am using twitter bootstrap for css. I am using .dropdown-toggle class to display a dropdown box when a link is hovered on.

I want the main menu link to have the background color of white when I am hovering on dropdown box menu items.
The css that I am using does not work.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

  <div class="navbar-inner">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
       <span class="page-title" data-bind="text: router.activeItem().title"></span>
        <ul class="nav" data-bind="foreach: router.visibleRoutes">
          <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive}" class="navLi">
              <a data-bind="text: name" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu qaDropdown" data-bind="foreach: qaSubMenus">
                    <li class="navLi"> 
                        <a data-bind="attr: { href: '#/' + url }, text: name" href="#"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

           </li>
          </ul>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</nav>


.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover .dropdown-toggle{
     background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the css below solved the problem:

```
.navLi:hover .dropdown-toggle{
      color:black;
}

.navLi:hover {
   background-color:white;
}
```